# Adding Simple Text to Woocommerce Email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The current email is attached here. I'd like to add one line that says "for seller resources go to www.domain.com/slug." How would I add this text w/ link to this email? (I have next to 0 php skills but trying to learn).

[image]

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'Thanks for creating an account on %1$s. Your username is %2$s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $blogname ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_login ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>

<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) && $password_generated ) : ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'Your password has been automatically generated: %s', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_pass ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'You can access your account area to view your orders and change your password here: %s.', 'woocommerce' ), make_clickable( esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) ); ?></p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Comment: Where do you wish to add your new code? There are 2 action hooks, `woocommerce_email_header` and `woocommerce_email_footer`, which could probably serve.

Comment: I'd love to add it right after the "thanks for creating an account" line. Can I just copy the format of the current <?php if( statements but enter my own message?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could try adding this snippet to your theme's `functions.php` or ideally in a site-specific plugin:

```
function so_45897243_add_text_to_email( $email ) {
    if( 'customer_new_account' == $email->id ) {
        echo "for seller resources go to www.domain.com/slug.";
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', 'so_45897243_add_text_to_email', 5 );
```

You may also need

```
function so_45897243_add_text_to_email_plain( $text ) {
    $new = "for seller resources go to www.domain.com/slug.";
    return $new . "\n\n" . $text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_footer_text', 'so_45897243_add_text_to_email_plain' );
```

for plain text emails, but there currently doesn't seem to be a way to limit which emails that is added to.

Or you could override the `emails/customer-new-account.php` and `emails/plain/customer-new-account.php` templates in your theme. Then you can add your text directly. I try to keep my template overrides to a minimum as it makes upgrading WooCommerce easier in the future.

**EDIT** Sample override template:

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer new account email
 *
 * Save this template in yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account.php.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'Thanks for creating an account on %1$s. Your username is %2$s', 'your-theme' ), esc_html( $blogname ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_login ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>

    <p><?php _e( 'For seller resources go to <a href="http://wwww.domain.com/slug">www.domain.com/slug</a>.', 'your-theme' ); ?></p>

<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) && $password_generated ) : ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'Your password has been automatically generated: %s', 'your-theme' ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_pass ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'You can access your account area to view your orders and change your password here: %s.', 'your-theme' ), make_clickable( esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) ); ?></p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I have basically 0 php knowledge and trying to hack this together as I learn. Definitely agree about having too many direct overrides (although this does work in a child theme). For now, if I was going to just enter an extra line in that cutomer-new-account.php file, how would I go about that? Thanks!

Comment: Docs on [overriding templates](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/). Once you have copied the relevant template into your theme, you can add your text where you need it.

Comment: thank you - I just don't know how to actually write the php code in the override.

Comment: Please see my edit. You could just echo it out, but it's a good habit to make everything translatable.